# Install PIL: build_ext success, but selftest fail

Tags: python-imaging-library

PIL build can find component. But selftest.py failed.

```
# python setup.py clean
# python setup.py build_ext -i
```

It shows as below.

```
*** TKINTER support not available (Tcl/Tk 8.5 libraries needed)
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
```

But selftest fail as shown below.
    # python selftest.py

```
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
*** JPEG support not installed
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
*****************************************************************
Failure in example:
try:
 _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
except IOError, v:
 print v
from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

I have create the link as shown below:

```
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so -> /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/libz.so -> /usr/lib64/libz.so
/lib/libz.so.1 -> /lib64/libz.so.1
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What version of Python are you using. I'm trying to do the same thing you are but with python2.4 without success on a 64-bit. I use Centos and I've tested both 5 & 6 32-bit and they worked fine. However on a 64-bit host I get the exact same output. Have you found, or does my info provide you with a possible solution??